# How to refresh Capybara URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, webautomation

I've been playing with Capybara and the selenium web-driver to learn about web-automation. I've been trying to refresh a particular page with Capybara. I've seen a few methods but they each have issues that make them not feasible in certain cases.

session.visit link is just doing nothing, as the session is already at that link.
I can do session.reset! but then I lose the login.

The few other methods I've seen - don't use Capybara's inbuilt wait functionality.
This means if there is heavy server load - or in my tests with a restricted DL/UL rate the 'refresh' happens but then it quickly tries to look for a field in the next page that doesn't exist yet because it hasn't loaded.

So my question is specifically - how do I refresh a page in Capybara without loosing the login session using Capybara's inbuilt wait functionality?

Answer (score 8):

Capybara now implements a [`refresh`](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/8c4bffda867c9edc4c5a7b8d37738065775f9945/lib/capybara/session.rb#L285-L288) method so you can call it directly in your spec.

Answer (score 5):

you can do something like:

```
visit current_path
```

or define an RSpec helper:

```
def reload_page
  visit current_path
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using selenium, you can either use the master branch of Capybara and call

```
session.refresh
```

or you can stick with the current release version and call

```
session.driver.browser.navigate.refresh
```

If the page you're trying to refresh was a POST it may pop up an "are you sure you want to resbumit" modal, in which case you'd need something like

```
session.accept_confirm do
  session.driver.browser.navigate.refresh
end
```

Comment: Does session.refresh wait for the page to reload? Imagine this page is running very slow now and I have session.refresh then session.click_button("Button_play"). If Button_play is not live yet - but may be after a refresh - will session.refresh wait?

Comment: @Leon92 Page loads are never guaranteed to wait.  You need to set an expectation for whatever is changing after the page refreshes.  If Button_play didn't exist prior to the refresh then `click_button('Button_play')` would wait for the button to appear (up to Capybara.default_wait_time seconds).  If you need it to potentially wait longer you can specify that in the `click_button` call - `click_button('Button_play', wait: 60)` - will wait up to a minute for 'Button_play' to appear and then click it.